# Extract everything after 3rd dash and before 4th dash in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel, I'm trying to extract everything after 3rd dash and before 4th dash. I'm struggling to find the solution on StackOverflow, although I know it's probably here.

Spreadsheet A1 column:

```
e:\uye_SCRAPE\jwioef-SCC-PI-DLP-00001_WIP.pdf
e:\uye_SCRAPE\jwioef-SCC-PI-MDS-00001_WIP.pdf
e:\uye_SCRAPE\jwioef-SCC-PI-MDS-00001_WIP.pdf
e:\uye_SCRAPE\jwioef-SCC-PI-QRS-00001_WIP.pdf
```

Ouput:

```
DLP
MDS
MDS
QRS
```

Comment: Working back from the 0, you could use `=MID(A1,FIND("0",A1)-4,3)`

Comment: Or forward from the "PI", and yes, there are **many** examples on here. You could also specify the start point as a fixed number...

Comment: What version of Excel? Also, how diverse is your data? Asking since the current sample data is structured in such a way you can simply use MID. I suppose that's not the case though.